# How to formally define a conditional distribution conditioning on an event of probability zero?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, measure-theory, conformal-prediction

Given $[X,Y]\sim N(0,I_2)$, a intuitive guess of the value of $P(X=x|\{X,Y\}=\{x,y\})$, where $\{\}$ means unordered set,  is $1/2$ by symmetry. This type of notations is typically applied in conformal inference with assumption about exchangeability (see [*Conformal Prediction Under Covariate Shift*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.06019)).
[image: In Conformal Prediction Under Covariate Shift]
For things like $P(X|Y=y)$, we know the regular conditional probability[image: Regular conditional probability]
(see [Regular conditional probability in Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability)), and the conditions required for the latter one can be find in many statistic textbooks (e.g. [Mathematical Statistics by Shao jun](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97553)).

However, $set\{\}$ cannot be simply treated as a random variable or a measurable function about random variables, so it obscures the $\sigma$-algebra conditioned on. The question is how to regularize the underlying probability space in order to construct the respective regular conditional distribution.

Comment: How exactly does some concept of symmetry imply this result?

Comment: It is either event $\{X=1, Y=-1\}$ or event $\{X=-1, Y=1\}$ happens.

Comment: Thank you -- it would have been clearer just to state that explicitly.

Comment: How is this different than any other conditional  probability w.r.t a continuous variable?

Comment: Since we have density,  it is quite straightforward to verify that we are indeed defining a regular condition probability.

Comment: So where is the problem ?

Comment: Please do not give new information only in comments, edit 
 your question to add the new information. We want posts to 
 be self-contained, comments can be deleted, and anyhow, 
 information in comments are not well organized. Also, many 
 people do not read comments.

Comment: Sry for my delay. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formal definition can be done by the theory of measurable correspondence. Situation here is trivial since we only need a $\sigma$-algebra with measure. Intuitively, here we can fold the $R^2$ along the $y=x$ and double the measure.